# x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (50,) and (10,)

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapes, diagram, dimension

I want to plot a diagram with 2 arrays but it is not working.
Output says:

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (50,) and (10,)

Thank u so much!!!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p = float(input("Introduzca probabilidad de error de bit: "))
while p < 0 or p > 1:
     p = float(input("Introduzca probabilidad de error de bit: "))
n = int(input("Introduzca número de bits: "))
while n < 0:
     n = int(input("Introduzca número de bits: "))

q = 1-p
pexito = q**n
intentos = 1/pexito
print()
print("El número medio de intentos es:",intentos)
print()
print("La probabilidad de transmitir correctamente",n,"bits es:",pexito)

listapmf = []
listacdf = []

for i in range(n):
    pmf = (p**(n-1))*q
    listapmf.append(pmf)
for j in range(n):
    cdf = 1-(p**n)
    listacdf.append(cdf)

arraycdf = np.array(listacdf)
arraypmf = np.array(listapmf) 

x1 = np.linspace(0.0, n)
x2 = np.linspace(0.0, n)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(x1, arraypmf, '.-')
plt.title('Intentos de transmisión en base a una probabilidad de error de bit')
plt.ylabel('PMF')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(x2, arraycdf, '.-')
plt.xlabel('Intentos')
plt.ylabel('CDF')

plt.show()
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. According to the error, your `x` value has 50 elements, and your `y` value has only 10 elements, so it cannot be plotted together

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: I just edited it because it really didn't add anything meaningful to the post or question itself.

Comment: me pedía un número mínimo de letras!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As G.Anderson stated, the problem is you are trying to plot 50 x-axis values with only 10 x-axis values. The issue starts when you define `x1` and `x2`. The default for `np.linspace()` is to split the values passed in 50 values. I'm not sure what are you expecting, but maybe this would work? (Functionally it does work 100% but not sure if it's the logic you intend to use)

Error:

```
x1 = np.linspace(0.0, n) <-- Split values between 0 and n in 50 values
x2 = np.linspace(0.0, n) <-- Same
```

Change to:

```
x1 = np.linspace(0.0, 1, num = n)
x2 = np.linspace(0.0, 1, num = n)
```

Comment: No hay problema! :D